# Probability: Conditioning on two givens?

Tags: probability

How do I condition on two givens? Say I want to find $P(L_1 > t | \max(L_1, L_2) > t)$, and I want to condition on the instance that $L_1 > L_2$. How does the notation work, and is this even acceptable?

Comment: You mean $P\left({L_{1} > t} \;\vert\; {\max\{ L_1, L_2 \} >t},  {L_1 > L_2}\right)$? If yes, that would be acceptable. That probability is equal to $1$ though!

Comment: In this case, the desired probability is actually equal to $P(L_1>t|L_1>t)=1$ because if $L_1>L_2$, then $L_1=\max(L_1,L_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation means that you are restricting your probability space $\Omega$ to where the condition holds. Since $L_1>t$ everywhere in this space, the probability is $1$

Comment: $\Omega$ is not a probability space

Comment: Sample space then